# Using attributes of one class in another class

Tags: java, class, methods, attributes, assert

I am trying to move the assertThat method from Authentication class to the BDDStyledMethod class but the current code will generate the following error "'Creds(java.lang.String)' in 'steps.Authentication' cannot be applied to '()'"

How do i correct my code so that the assertThat method works in the BDDStyledMethod class ?

```
public class Authentication {
 public static void Creds(String url){
        RequestSpecification httpRequest=RestAssured.given()
                .auth().oauth2(Authentication.login("user","password"));

        Response response = httpRequest.get(url);
        ResponseBody body=response.getBody();

        body.prettyPrint();
        System.out.println("The status received: " + response.statusLine());
        assertThat("They are not the same",response.statusLine(),is("HTTP/1.1 200"));

    }

}
```

```
public class BDDStyledMethod {

    public static void GetActivityById(){

        Authentication.Creds("www.randomurl.com");
        assertThat("They are not the same",Authentication.Creds().response.statusLine(),is("HTTP/1.1 200"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the Creds method. It is not returning anything and the exception is raised in this line -> Authentication.Creds().response.statusLine()
We can return a string from Creds method and then try to apply assert() on the returned string in GetActivityById class.

```
    public class Authentication {
    public static String Creds(String url){
    RequestSpecification httpRequest=RestAssured.given()
            .auth().oauth2(Authentication.login("user","password"));

    Response response = httpRequest.get(url);
    ResponseBody body=response.getBody();

    body.prettyPrint();
    System.out.println("The status received: " + response.statusLine());
    return response.statusLine().toString();

        }

    }
```

> 

```
public class BDDStyledMethod {

public static void GetActivityById(){

    String returned_str = Authentication.Creds("www.randomurl.com");
    assertThat("They are not the same",returned_str,is("HTTP/1.1 200"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this solves my problem for now but if I also want to return a statusCode (instead of a statusLine), which is an integer, it will not let me use the toString method because you are not allowed to use methods on primitive types. How would i have to proceed if i wanted to have both ?

Comment: In that case just return response object. Of course, change return type to Response in your Creds method. In  GetActivityById method, apply any method on the returned response object.